# Why did Dumbledore not face Voldemort earlier like he did for Grindlewald

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, albus-dumbledore

We know that Dumbledore marched and faced Grindelwald on his own. However why did he not do the same for Voldemort before? What was he waiting for or was he afraid of facing Voldemort?